# passing JCombobox value to Start button

Tags: java, combobox

I have a gui with combobox and start button. I want a start button to do an action depending on combobox choice. Here is my combobox code:

```
private void jCbxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                      
    if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        Object item = jCbx.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Object item1=new Object();
        Object item2=new Object();
        Object item3=new Object();

        if (item.equals("1"))
        {
          System.out.println("ip 1");
          item=item1;

        }
        if (item.equals("2"))
        {
            System.out.println("ip 2");
            item=item2;

            if (item.equals("3"))
            {
              System.out.println("ip 3");
              item=item3;
            }
        }                                     
    }
```

I want to pass saved combobox choice to start button and do an action depending on user choice:

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Display Ping")) {
        System.out.println("Display ping: ");

        pingmain p= new pingmain();
        String ip = "ping google.com";  
        p.runSystemCommand(ip);

        //I want to read value from combobox and depending if item1 was choosen i would do 
        // new  String ip ="ping ipExample1", if item2 String ip2="ping ipExample2" 
        // Pseudocode: if item 1 do ip example 1, if item 2 do ip example 2
        GUI_COMPLETE = true;

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing the value of an event throwed by the JButton....

When processing the JButton event, just access to your JCombobox and get the value selected.

Or maybe better if all of this can communicate : during changes of the choice on JComboBox, update a String attribute, then test and process it on button click.

During JComboBox event :

> myChoosenValue = "ipExemple"+jcbb.getSelectedItem().toString();

with myChoosenValue set as private attribute of your class

Then, you don't really need to duplicate your if statements on the button click if it's just for a String. Else, test your "myChoosenValue", and do the process with it.
But it's only possible if your two components are used on the same class, else it starts to be more complex, so use following during button click

```
String value = getJCBB().getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then process the string for your need. getJCBB() should be a method that allows you to access to your JComboBox constructed :

```
public JComboBox getJCBB(){
    if(jcbb == null){
       // Do init here
    }
    return jcbb;
}
```

But you need jcbb to be an attribute.

And if needed, the total is something like this :

> class UI{

```
private Map<String,String> ips; // Keys are jcbb values, values are ip your need
private JComboBox jcbb;

public UI(){
    initIPS(); // fill here your map data, don't forget to instanciate it as HashMap<>
    // Do some layouts putting...
    X.add(getJCBB(), BorderLayour.NORTH); // for example
}

public JComboBox getJCBB(){
    if(jcbb == null){
        jcbb = new JComboBox();
        //Add here data
    }
    return jcbb;
}

// Now here during your process buttin event
String ip = ips.get(getJCBB().getSelectedItem().toString()); // Acess to the ip pointed with the JCBB choice
//Process 
}
```

Comment: Edited.
And another thing : why do you need this String item declared ? It's useless here, deleted at the end of your event process.

Comment: thanks a lot seems logical and simplier than what i had. But, how do i pass this to start button and how do i change ip adress search on button depending on user choice?

Comment: Use the string got from any one of theses two part of code, and apply an ip depending of the value of this string.
Directly, if you want an ip adress, use a Map<String, String> as attribute : keys are selected item, values are the ip corresponding to. Good way if you want your JComboBox to display "localhost project 1" instead of "localhost:X/Y/Z". Then use the String got before to access to this IP value.

Comment: @swipeales Edited one more time, but with more complete code. Try to adapt it to your code, it should work ;)